# How to get a dictionary with the lowest key value

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my dictionary schema.

```
f = { 'client_id': {'client_name': [{'transaction_date': date_time,
                                     'transaction_amount': value_in_dollar}]
                   }
    }
```

How to get a dictionary with the lowest transaction_amount.

Example input :

```
f = { 905220: {'Steven Jhon': [{'transaction_date': '2016-05-07 00:00:00+00',
                              'transaction_amount': 1198},
                             {'transaction_date': '2016-05-08 00:00:00+00',
                              'transaction_amount': 4889}]
              },
      905221: {'Chris Chris': [{'transaction_date': '2016-05-01 00:00:00+00',
                                  'transaction_amount': 50},
                                 {'transaction_date': '2016-05-02 00:00:00+00',
                                  'transaction_amount': 100},
                                 {'transaction_date': '2016-05-03 00:00:00+00',
                                  'transaction_amount': 10}]
               }     
    }
```

desired output :

```
f = { 905220: {'Steven Jhon': [{'transaction_date': '2016-05-07 00:00:00+00',
                              'transaction_amount': 1198}]
              },
      905221: {'Chris Chris': [{'transaction_date': '2016-05-03 00:00:00+00',
                                  'transaction_amount': 10}]
               }     
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What difficulties are you having in your current approach?

Comment: It seems like it would be better to have this data in a database as retrieving data by value from a dict is quite inefficient. Are you able to move this to a DB? What is our use case?

Comment: @IanAuld the data was already in the database and I had to pull clients info from the database and feed the id to an API to get the transaction details and I combined the both sets in the dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a big dict comprehension, or a helper function like this one:

```
def get_min_by_value(x):
  if isinstance(x, dict):
    return {k: get_min_by_value(v) for k, v in x.items()}
  elif isinstance(x, list):
    return [min(x, key=lambda d: d['transaction_amount'])]

out = get_min_by_value(f)
```